# How to quickly retrieve a lot of data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get 6 numbers from "INCLUDE_NUMBER_T", make the numbers in all cases and put them in "NUMBER_TOTAL_T".

It takes about 37 seconds to run and I want to run faster.

INCLUDE_NUMBER_T in data

```
includeNum
----------
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    .
    .
    .
```

NUMBER_TOTAL_T Example data

```
num1  num2  num3  num4  num5  num6
 1     2     3     4     5     6
 2     3     4     5     6     7
 2     4     5     6     7     8
               .
               .
               .
```

my sql code

```
;WITH TEMP(N) AS (
SELECT includeNum
    FROM INCLUDE_NUMBER_T
)
INSERT INTO NUMBER_TOTAL_T(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6,createTime)
SELECT num1.N
            ,num2.N
            ,num3.N
            ,num4.N
            ,num5.N
            ,num6.N
            ,dbo.FncGetToday()
    FROM TEMP num1
        JOIN TEMP num2
            ON num2.N > num1.N
        JOIN TEMP num3
            ON num3.N > num2.N
        JOIN TEMP num4
            ON num4.N > num3.N
        JOIN TEMP num5
            ON num5.N > num4.N
        JOIN TEMP num6
            ON num6.N > num5.N
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1)
```

Comment: Its not `NEWID()` which is making it run slow. Take it out for a test and see.

Comment: Hi @seungyong, what should `FncGetToday` be ? Cheers!

Comment: @VBoka Get today's date! EX) 2019-12-03 16:07:34.683

Comment: Capture the result of that function in a variable, that way it won't need to be executed for each row. Also, ordering makes no sense when inserting data. Order is not preserved in the target table.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - it makes a difference if the target table has an `IDENTITY` column  - as this will then be assigned in the order of the `ORDER BY`. ` `@seungyong` Why do you have `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1)` when you aren't using a recursive CTE? How many rows are in `INCLUDE_NUMBER`? Maybe the number of permutations is just quite high

Comment: @Martin Smith - "INCLUDE NUMBER" contains an average of 34 numbers, with 1344904 results in all 34 cases.

Answer (score 0):

How much rows in `INCLUDE_NUMBER_T`? If the data is just like your example, maybe you can try my query sql:

```
insert into NUMBER_TOTAL_T (num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, createTime)
select 
    a.includeNum as num1, 
    b.includeNum as num2, 
    c.includeNum as num3,
    d.includeNum as num4,
    e.includeNum as num5,
    f.includeNum as num6,
    getdate()
from INCLUDE_NUMBER_T a
inner join INCLUDE_NUMBER_T b on a.includeNum+1=b.includeNum
inner join INCLUDE_NUMBER_T c on b.includeNum+1=c.includeNum
inner join INCLUDE_NUMBER_T d on c.includeNum+1=d.includeNum
inner join INCLUDE_NUMBER_T e on d.includeNum+1=e.includeNum
inner join INCLUDE_NUMBER_T f on e.includeNum+1=f.includeNum
```

Function `getdate()` is to get current datetime. If this query still slow, then you can try add Index to column `includeNum` in `INCLUDE_NUMBER_T`. Here query to add index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_indexname ON INCLUDE_NUMBER_T(includeNum)
```

I already tested with 1000000 record in table `INCLUDE_NUMBER_T`, and only get < 10s.

Comment: "INCLUDE NUMBER" contains an average of 34 numbers, with 1344904 results in all 34 cases.

Comment: I tested this but only duplicate numbers came out.

Comment: you can add "DISTINCT" in query select... so the query became like this: "select distinct"